# Access to Docker container

Tags: docker, lamp

I have a `LAMP` with a lot of added domain names, so many different websites are stored on it. I would like to separate them into `Docker` containers. Every websites/webapps and all related stuffs should be in a container. File access is solved with `--volumes-from` flag, but what about `MySQL` databases and `VirtualHosts`? How should I set them in a per container way?

Comment: What is the problem with `VirtualHosts`?

Answer (score 1):

For MYSQL you could launch  one for each container and then link them together using the --link flag. Or you could simply install mysql as server within the docker container itself.

You could also probalby use docker-compose to orchestrate each as a whole.

As for virtual hosts, the following would probably meet your demands?

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Comment: If I have already running containers with exposed ports, how can I tell `nginx-proxy`, which ports should be mapped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the already available [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) image to start your DB and then connect it either through linking (`--link` option when running your app), you can find more info in the link.

For you virtualhosts you can use nginx as a proxy and it will route to your apps depending on your criteria (e.g. `/admin` will be routed to `app1-192.197.0.12`).

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the MySQL port in dockerfile by using ÈXPOSE` command and then bind your service to divert MySQL related queries on that port.